# SQL query for any value

Tags: sql

I'm building SQL queries on the fly and am a bit of a beginner with them.

How would I do something like:

`Select * from X where Type = *Any*`

Basically, I want to select all of them. I know I could not include the where but often times the Type variable does in fact have values. I want to be able to replace the "Any" part with something else on the fly rather than a whole different expression...

Comment: What specific database variant you use? MySQL? MS-SQL ? it really will affect some answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from X where Type Like '%';
```

Comment: Why the downvote? % in this case is a variable that you can pass in and will keep your query the same

Comment: Someone possibly downvoted because you didn't provide any explanation of your code. Editing your comment into your answer would be a good start - then expand and explain why your code works.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
--please change the datatype int to match your datatype for type column
DECLARE @type int = 1;  

SELECT * FROM X 
WHERE x.[Type] = COALESCE(@type,x.[type]);
```

If you don't pass a value in variable `@type`, it will default to your type and return everything. Otherwise, it will supply the variable value as needed. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

This kind of depends on what your SQL implementation is. That being said the two concepts you are missing are using the keyword "LIKE" instead of "=", and using wildcards. I advise going through W3Schools SQL section to get started, or better yet buy some introduction to SQL book. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

```
SELECT * FROM X
WHERE Type LIKE '%';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want *everything* it is simple:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table
```

There is no `where` clause , in this case. You usually want to first try something like this , though:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table
WHERE rownum < 2
```

But rownum is an Oracle-specific column. You need to look it up for your specific database .